# Move googletest source files outside of directory-tree

Tags: c++, c, cmake, googletest

This is my current directory structure:

```
projectFolder/CMakeLists.txt
projectFolder/src       /* holds all project .cpp files */
projectFolder/include   /* holds all header files*/
projectFolder/test      /* holds all test .cpp files*/
projectFolder/ext/gtest /* holds all files associated with googletest, 
                           including it's CMakeLists.txt file */
```

What currently works is:

1. build files in `projectFolder/ext/gtest` with cmake and ninja
2. build files in `projectFolder` with cmake and ninja

The disatvantage is that googletest is in a subdirectory of my project, which means I would have to duplicate its source files for every project

What I would like to do is remove the source files of googletest from the project directory tree and move it to a `3rdParty` folder. I then want to be able to compile google test whenever I use cmake and ninja from inside a projects `build` folder, effectively creating separate binaries for each project I have, without having to have the source files in the project's diretory tree (binaries would be created new in a sub-directory of the project's `build` folder.)

When I move the `gtest` out of the project folder, I get the following error:

```
When specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory 
must be explicitly specified.
```

When I specify a binary directory with `add_subdirectory(${EXT_PROJECTS_DIR}/gtest ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest)` I get

```
ninja: error: 
    'gtest/src/googletest-build/libgtest.a', needed by 
    'google-test-examples_test', missing and no known rule to make it
```

I have tried to link googletest with `find_package`, but cmake doesn't find googletest. Also, I am not sure that when I use `find_package` the binaries get recompiled for each project, could someone verify or refute this?

I am on a Mac running lion

Comment: I haven't tested [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9695234/2556117) on a Mac, but you could look at using `ExternalProject_Add` to just pull the gtest sources down to your build tree every time.

Comment: Since I haven't found anything that is more straight-forward, I am intrigued, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: If your only concern is to stop duplicating google-test sources why don't use symlink? It seems that Mac supports them. Then you can just `add_subdirectory` as you probably do now.

Comment: @Fraser: when compiling with ninja I get `ThirdParty does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.` Cmake creates some folders, but never starts to actually pull the sources.

Comment: @zaquest: I am hesitant to just symlink googletest, since all the sites I have scoured are full of warnings that each project should compile googletest itself (possibly different compiler flags and other issues that are a nightmare to debug)

Comment: @DudeOnRock Sorry - I don't have access to a Mac.  I've just tested on Ubuntu with Clang and GCC and it works (after a few modifications), but that probably isn't much help to you.