# Using cmake as the configure tool (CONFIGURE_COMMAND) in CMakes "Add_External_Project" function

Tags: cmake, external-project

I am having an issue with CMakes `Add_External_Project` functionality (more of an annoyance than anything else). Specifically, I do not understand the keys `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`, `BUILD_COMMAND` and `INSTALL_COMMAND`.

In the following (working) example, which downloads Google's test library, the two files at the end of the question will ensure that the third party libraries are downloaded and built (**not** installed).

However, when I tried to add configure and build commands as "CONFIGURE_COMMAND" and "BUILD_COMMAND" (`cmake .` and `cmake --build`) instead of having to do `execute_process` CMake craps out with the error message:

```
[ 55%] Performing configure step for 'googletest'
/bin/sh: 1: cmake .: not found
```

Am I trying to do something that is *obviously* not within the scope of the `Add_External_Project` functionality?

#### Example Files:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

project (Test VERSION 0.1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt.in" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt" @ONLY)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" . WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download" )

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download")

add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build")
```

`CMakeLists.txt.in`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(third-party NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` at all, it will assume a CMake project and run the appropriate `cmake` command for you (by appropriate, I mean it will use the same CMake generator as your main build, etc.). Similarly, if you leave out `BUILD_COMMAND`, it will also assume a CMake project and do `cmake --build` for you. So in your case, just leave out those two lines and `ExternalProject_Add()` should do exactly what you want.

The main reason you might specify these two options as empty strings is to prevent those steps from doing anything at all. This can be useful, for example, to use `ExternalProject_Add()` simply for its download and unpacking functionality. This exact situation is used in a technique described [here](https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/) for downloading the source of GoogleTest so it can be added to your project via `add_subdirectory()`, making it part of your build (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622855/1938798) and other answers to that question for some related material). I suspect this might be where your code is derived from, as the structure looks similar.

For completeness, if you find yourself in a situation where you *do* need to specify a CMake command, don't use a bare `cmake` to refer to the command to run. Instead, always use `${CMAKE_COMMAND}`, which is provided by CMake as the location of the CMake executable currently being used to process the file. Using this variable means `cmake` doesn't have to be on the user's `PATH` and also ensures that if the developer chooses to run a different version of CMake other than the one on the `PATH`, that same `cmake` will still be used for the command you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATCH_COMMAND` like this:

```
option(WITH_MBEDTLS "Build with mbedtls" OFF)
if(WITH_MBEDTLS)
  ExternalProject_Add(external-mbedtls
    URL https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/archive/mbedtls-2.16.1.tar.gz
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ./scripts/config.pl set MBEDTLS_THREADING_C &&
                  ./scripts/config.pl set MBEDTLS_THREADING_PTHREAD
    CMAKE_ARGS
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/mbedtls
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:PATH=${TOOLCHAIN_FILE}
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
      -DENABLE_TESTING:BOOL=OFF
      -DENABLE_PROGRAMS:BOOL=ON
    TEST_COMMAND ""
    )
    set(MBEDTLS_PREFIX ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/mbedtls PARENT_SCOPE)
endif(WITH_MBEDTLS)
```