# CMake - Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, undefined-reference

I am trying to include gtest to my project.

The problem is that I get a undefined reference error in the GTest.

I am trying to test the Node class in Gtest. Inside the constructor of the Node I am using the Class Logger. Although I have added the library logger to the gtest-target I still the undefined reference error regarding to the Logger....

My guess CMake does no look for nested classes that are used inside Node.
only Node itself.

**Temperoy fix**
If I use the Logger in the gtest-node.cpp it works
gtest.cpp

```
/* Pseudo Code */
TEST Node
{ 
     Logger::log("Temp Fix")
     Node * n = Node(0,0,0)
}
```

This way the the Logger is directly used in the gtest this way the logger-library will be add to the target by cmake.

My Setup (pseudo-code because my project is way bigger than this) 
(https://github.com/ronsalm/LearningLunch)

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── logger
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── logger.cpp
│   └── logger.h
├── Node
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── node.cpp
│   └── node.h
└── Gtest
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── gtest-node.cpp
    └── node.h
```

main.cpp

```
/* Pseudo Code */
int main()
{ 
     Node * n = Node(0,0,0)
}
```

logger.h

```
/* Pseudo Code */
class Logger
{ 
     log(string)
}
```

logger.cpp

```
/* Pseudo Code */
Logger::log(string s)
{
//write to string to file
}
```

node.h

```
/* Pseudo Code */
class Node
{ 
     Node(int,int,int)
}
```

node.cpp

```
/* Pseudo Code */
Node::node(int x, int y , int z)
{
     Logger::log("Create Node")
}
```

gtest.cpp

```
/* Pseudo Code */
TEST Node
{ 
     Node * n = Node(0,0,0)
}
```

CMakeLists.txt (Root)

```
project(applic)
include_directories(
      "${CMAKE_SOURE_DIR/node"
      "${CMAKE_SOURE_DIR/logger")

add_library(node node.cpp)
add_executable(applic main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(applic logger node)
```

CMakeLists.txt (Logger)

```
add_library(logger logger.cpp)
```

CMakeLists.txt (Node)

```
add_library(node node.cpp)
```

CMakeLists.txt (Gtest)

```
add_executable(gtest-node gtest-node.cpp)
set_target_properties(gtest-node PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(gtest-logger gtest phtread logger node)
add_test(NAME node COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:gtest-node>

enable_testing()
```

The original error:

```
../../../../lib/libdatabase.a(sql.cpp.o): In function `SQL::Open()':
/home/rsalm/test/src/database/sql/sql.cpp:19: undefined reference to `Logger::TagDebug'
/home/rsalm/test/src/database/sql/sql.cpp:19: undefined reference to `Logger::instance(std::string const&)                                               '
../../../../lib/libdatabase.a(sql.cpp.o): In function `SQL::Close()':
/home/rsalm/test/src/database/sql/sql.cpp:27: undefined reference to `Logger::TagDebug'
/home/rsalm/test/src/database/sql/sql.cpp:27: undefined reference to `Logger::instance(std::string const&)                                               '
../../../../lib/libdatabase.a(sql.cpp.o): In function `Logger& operator<< <char [25]>(Logger&, char const (&) [25])                                               ':
/home/rsalm/test/inc/logger.h:33: undefined reference to `Logger::pInstance'
../../../../lib/libdatabase.a(sql.cpp.o): In function `Logger& operator<< <char [21]>(Logger&, char const (&) [21])                                               ':
/home/rsalm/test/inc/logger.h:33: undefined reference to `Logger::pInstance'
../../../../lib/libdatabase.a(sql.cpp.o): In function `Logger& operator<< <char [26]>(Logger&, char const (&) [26])                                               ':
/home/rsalm/test/inc/logger.h:33: undefined reference to `Logger::pInstance'
../../../../lib/libdatabase.a(sql.cpp.o): In function `Logger& operator<< <char [24]>(Logger&, char const (&) [24])                                               ':
/home/rsalm/test/inc/logger.h:33: undefined reference to `Logger::pInstance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/layout/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest-layout-factory.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target '../bin/gtest-layout-factory'                                                failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/gtest-layout-factory] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1824: recipe for target 'src/layout/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest-layout-factory.dir/all' failed
```

Comment: You miss close brackets in `CMakeLists.txt` - `"${CMAKE_SOURE_DIR/node"` -> `"${CMAKE_SOURE_DIR}/node"` and `"${CMAKE_SOURE_DIR/logger` -> `"${CMAKE_SOURE_DIR}/logger"` .

Answer (score 4):

Your `node` library uses the `logger` library, but you haven't specified that link relationship. You need to add the following:

```
target_link_library(node PRIVATE logger)
```

Then, any time you link to `node`, CMake will append `logger` to the link libraries if `node` is built as a static library.

You *almost* get away with what you did with the linking of the `gtest-logger` target where you explicitly added the `logger` library there, assuming you actually meant `gtest-node` rather than `gtest-logger` in that call to `target_link_library()`. If you had listed `logger` after `node`, I would have expected the build to work (assuming the target name typo), but that would not be the correct way to do it. You should only need to explicitly list `logger` as a link dependency of `gtest-logger` if something in `gtest.cpp` directly referenced something from the `Logger` class.

Comment: You may also want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31622855/1938798) for an alternative way of bringing gtest into your build rather than embedding the sources.