# How to bring external dependencies into cross-platform CMake project?

Tags: c++, git, cmake, dependencies, dependency-management

What would be the best approach to bring external dependencies into cross-platform CMake project? See below the problem scope and solutions I see.

## Problem Scope

Let's say we have a C/C++ project with following constraints:

- CMake is the build system;
- Has to be built for different platforms (Desktops, Android NDK / Yocto SDK, iOS);
- Has external dependencies built with CMake (ex. Google Test);
- Has external non-CMake based dependencies (ex. SQLite amalgamation, Boost);
- Not all dependencies have Git upstream (ex. SQLite is kept in fossil).

Nice to have things:

- Dependencies are automatically downloaded, so that new devs have less steps to start coding;
- Dependencies are configured in a way that IDE's (like CLion) can do autocomplete (without extra configuration steps to be done).

## Possible Solutions

- Git Sub-modules (not clear what to do with non-Cmake based and not kept in Git dependencies);
- Google Repo tool (the same issues as for previous);
- CMake ExternalProject (download, unpack and potentially patch with CMakeLists.txt during generation phase and include to project with add_subdirectory).
  I have created a PoC[1] based on Craig Scott's[2] answer in [3].

## References

- [1] https://github.com/tegoo/cmake-dfetch
- [2] https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938798/craig-scott
- [3] [CMake + GoogleTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689183/cmake-googletest)

Comment: You have 2 approaches with downsides and one - ExternalProject - without them. So, why do not follow the third approach? What is a **question**?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I'm looking forward to know approaches I didn't think of.

Comment: Given such very generic information looking for approaches is just a "**recommendation**" question which we tend to avoid on Stack Overflow. We prefer to concentrate on a **specific problem** instead. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I think the topic is quite specific (given all the constraints) but also quite conceptual. Due to the lack of clear guidance in cases like that I think the question brings a good value.

Comment: Actually, these "constraints" have **vague** meaning. E.g. you write "Has to be built for different platforms ... Android NDK", and comment to the answer that `FetchContent` module is not accessible in Android NDK. But is this a real problem? One could easily **ship** his/her project with `FetchContent.cmake` module **copied** from official CMake for work in old CMake versions. Then, you want to work both with CMake and non-CMake-based dependencies. But what prevents to process these two kinds dependencies **differently**?

Comment: So you question is actually about processing external dependencies in CMake project in **general**. Far **too broad** for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PoC might work, but CMake has a built in [solution](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FetchContent.html) for fetching external projects during the configure step. If this does not satisfy your requirements like non CMake based dependencies, you may have a look at [Conan](https://conan.io/).

https://blog.conan.io/2018/06/11/Transparent-CMake-Integration.html

Comment: FetchContent is great and elides this ugly execution step in my PoC, but seems this module is not available in CMake version shipped with Android NDK.